# How to send the results of a lambda function to an email using aws sns

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, amazon-sns, multi-factor-authentication, identity-management

I have a lambda function that generates a list of users that are without MFA active, after generating this list, I wanted to send the output by email using SNS, but the current way it sends one user at a time and if I leave the publish outside the function, only a name is sent

```
    import json
    import boto3

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    sns_resource = boto3.resource('sns')
    TOPIC_ARN = 'sns_topic_arn'
    sns_topic = sns_resource.Topic(TOPIC_ARN)
    
    iam = boto3.resource('iam')
    users = iam.users.all()
    

    for user in users:
        has_any = any(user.mfa_devices.all())
        if not has_any:
            print(user.name)
            
    sns_topic.publish(Message=user.name)
```

Comment: Unclear what the goal is. Do you want to send one email to N users, do you want send N emails to N users, do you want to send N emails to one user, do you want to send one email to one user? The `publish` should be inside the for loop.

Comment: I want to send to only one, which is registered in SNS Subscriptions.

When I leave the publish inside the loop, an email is sent to each user that the loop detects

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you basically just need to collect the names outside the loop and push that into the message to SNS.  Using join is a common pattern.  Something like this:

```
import json
import boto3

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    sns_resource = boto3.resource('sns')
    TOPIC_ARN = 'sns_topic_arn'
    sns_topic = sns_resource.Topic(TOPIC_ARN)
    
    iam = boto3.resource('iam')
    users = iam.users.all()
    
    naughty_list = []
    for user in users:
        has_any = any(user.mfa_devices.all())
        if not has_any:
            naughty_list.append(user.name)
            
    sns_topic.publish(Message="Naughty list users: \n{}".format("\n".join(naughty_list)))
```